# Xcode 11 beta 5 Abort trap: 6 error when calling sink on @Published variable

Tags: swift, beta, xcode11, combine

I had a `@Published` variable to indicate my user state in one of my repository classes.

```swift
@Published public var state: UserState = .initial
```

In testing, I used `sink` to easily observe the changes and fullfill the expectation my test was waiting for.

The original test code looked like this:

```swift
sub = Authentication.shared.$state.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink(receiveValue: { state in
    expectation.fulfill()
})
Authentication.shared.login(with: Credentials(email: "gujci@gmail.com", password: "asdasd"))
```

Which resulted in a compiler error like the following `Abort trap: 6`

```
Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!
i64* @"$s14TestRepository14AuthenticationC6_state33_B23F0E9C543FDF10733C02EF2F1E18CCLL7Combine9PublishedVyAA9UserStateOGvpWvd"
<unknown>:0: error: fatal error encountered during compilation; please file a bug report with your project and the crash log
<unknown>:0: note: Broken module found, compilation aborted!
Stack dump:
...
```

The project where this occurs is in a separate swift package than the application.

When I have tried to use it from the application (no from tests) the result was the same. Also, I have tried other publishers eg. `Just` and `Future` returning from the network calls, all of them worked fine with `sink`.

I had this issue since beta 4, but never tried in previous ones, might be present in those as well. I have noticed there were huge changes for Combine between beta 4 and 5, yet, the error persists.

Has anybody managed to use the `sink` function on a `@Published` variable from an external library without such errors?

If I have misinterpreted something, please correct me, for now I have to assume, the problem is at Apple's end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have solved it with omitting the `@Published` keyword, by directly defining a publisher

```swift
public private(set) var state: CurrentValueSubject<UserState, Never> = .init(.initial)
```

Which can be used similarly.

It made me think, that `@Published` is only good for interfacing with SwiftUI, one layer deeper I should use explicit publishers from `Combine`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: can you please explain how do you use this publisher instead of `@Published`? I've ran into the same situation trying to split implementation of my `ObservableObject` into a superclass and a subclass, tried to change my `@Published` variables to `CurrentValueSubject`s, and now SwiftUI doesn't rerender when I change the value of these variables. I've tried to use `send()` and also tried to just reinit them every time. Do I need to subscribe somewhere to these variables in SwiftUI view?

Comment: If you have a non `@Published` in a ViewModel, you have to call `objectWillChange.send()` manually to notify the SwiftUI view. Since you can subscribe to a `CurrentValueSubject` easily, you can call it in a `sink`. Just don't forget to use main runloop and also store the subscription. (I use usually `private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []` for that purpose)